# How to hash session IDs for the database?

Tags: php

Specifically, I am doing this in PHP, but this question is not about the built-in PHP session mechanism; I am creating my own authentication system for experimental/educational purposes.

"Don't make your own system" isn't a helpful answer here because I want to understand the conceptual issue at hand regardless of that.

Here is the problem:

1. Session IDs are sensitive in much the same way as passwords and should be stored with similar security (hashes)
2. Regular cryptographic hash functions are now widely decried as worthless for this use because of their speed.
3. Modern password-hashing algorithms have features that make them inconvenient for hashing the session ID.

Let me explain #3.

The session ID is of course a long random string stored in a cookie -- the system compares the hash of this to the hashed session IDs in the database to verify a valid session, look up which session to use, and from there know which user they're logged in as and so on.
Unlike passwords, the session IDs are long, random, and guaranteed unique so having a separate salt for each one is not very valuable. Therefore you can use a system wide salt, allowing you to hash the input once and look up the session in the database based on that hash.

However, password-hashing functions (at least, their forms available in PHP) always auto generate a salt for you (providing a salt is either disallowed or deprecated) and append it to the hash output, and comparing an input against the hash involves using a special verify function that uses the salt stored with the hash to hash the input and compare.
This means that, when using password hashing for session IDs, there is no way to quickly look up the session based on the session ID, instead it requires re-hashing the input to separately compare against every session in the system, unfeasible especially considering this happens on every HTTP request.

Possible solutions I have considered:

1. Give each session an autoincrement integer ID which also appears in the cookie. This way, the "session ID"  will function as more of a session-specific password, instead of doing double duty as a password and ID. The integer will be used for lookup. This still doesn't let someone hijack a session by crafting a cookie with info they get from a database leak (or just guessing); they need the pre-hashed SID which is a long random string only appearing in the user's cookie. The disadvantage I can see is that, in the event of a cookie stealing attack, the attacker will know which session the SID corresponds to without calculating any hashes or actually attempting to hijack the session. Combined with a database leak they'll also know which user the session is for and so on. This doesn't seem like that big of a deal though. Additionally, I feel like I might be missing something bigger because there must be some reason why session management traditionally has only used a session ID (also treated as a password) in the cookie rather than a separate session ID and session-specific password.
2. Use Keccak for hashing session IDs and accept that session IDs don't need the same level of database leak mitigation as passwords, considering that the application requires re-authentication for sensitive actions like changing the user's password/email/etc and sessions have both an idle and absolute timeout

Comment: *"Session IDs are sensitive in much the same way as passwords"* - no, they're not. They're sort-term disposable identifiers passed around without HTTPS protection either via cookie or (occasionally) in the address bar.

Comment: The hash does not actually perform any “security functionality” here. The session id is based on a random value; it is only hashed so that you get a predictable _length_ of the resulting id.

Comment: @CD001 I think OP's point there is that a bit of SQL injection to spit out a session ID gives you roughly as much (albeit temporary) access as having that user's password.

Comment: *"Unlike passwords, the session IDs are long, random, and **guaranteed unique**"* - that's not strictly true; they're only unique at any given moment in time. A defunct session id *could* be recycled at any given point in the future.

Comment: @ceejayoz - not necessarily; there should probably be some additional authentication beyond `$_SESSION['logged_in'] == true;` by its nature the session id must exist in a cookie (or URL) and be available to the site unencrypted (unless your entire site is under HTTPS) - so it can be sniffed, especially on a public wifi network. So there would probably be an additional *https only* auth cookie or similar required when determining whether a user is logged in.

Comment: @CD001 Sniffing requires being on the same network. A SQL vuln that lets me get session IDs from the database means I can create a cookie and be logged in as you from anywhere in the world. HTTP vs. HTTPS is a red herring, IMO - you're already screwed eight different ways if it's HTTP on a public network anyways.

Comment: @ceejayoz - I did say on a public wifi network for sniffing. However, there's no guarantee that the session id will be stored in the database; there's no real need unless you're using db session storage. Even if it is having *my* current session cookie should *not* necessarily mean you're *authenticated* as me; depends on how you deal with user authentication.

Comment: Most of these points are not material to the question, in some cases because they've missed the detail that the absolute statements made in the question are in the context of my application and server configuration, not universal, and can thus be trusted in the context of answering the question. For example, plain HTTP is not allowed, only HTTPS.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is downvoted so much instead of answered. There are situations where hashing the session ID makes sense. Not all session IDs are short-lived (define 'short' right?) depending on the requirements, I have seen frameworks with extremely long defaults. As @ceejayoz says, he might be thinking of the SQL injection case, in which case one has access to all sessions that are currently active. However, my understanding is that most frameworks don't bother since they use signed cookies, so the session ID alone, is useless. If not, it could be a good measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP function [hash_pbkdf2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) does not generate it's own salt nor does it append a salt to the output.

`string hash_pbkdf2 ( string $algo , string $password , string $salt , int $iterations [, int $length = 0 [, bool $raw_output = false ]] )`

The caller controls the output length, salt, iteration count and there are 45 [hash algorythms](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php) to choose from.